# Reading URL for downloading a public json repository

Tags: python, json, url

I am trying to import some json data into python file. I am giving my code below. I am getting the error: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 8` . It would be  great if somebody explained what I am missing. I tried two ways and commenting out one.

thanks.

Code:

```py
import json
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen("https://github.com/Ovi/DummyJSON/blob/master/src/data/carts.json") as url:
    pydc=json.loads(url.read().decode())
    print(pydc)    

#with open("https://github.com/PhonePe/pulse/tree/master/data/aggregated/transaction/country/india/2018/1.json")  as file:
#    data=json.load(file)
#    print(data)
```

I am getting a `JSON Decode error` or "`unable to find the file or directory`".

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what happened there. This might need further testing but based on what I can see:

First, `open()` is just for opening local files, that's why opening `https://github.com/Ovi/DummyJSON/blob/master/src/data/carts.json` fails.

Second, the JSON decode error indicates the returned json document has some issues (in line 8). Muhammad Ovi seems to have written a valid document here though.
The issue might be that you're trying to parse a json document that isn't actually a json document but rather the GitHub interface for human users. Try printing the document to the terminal. If all you're seeing is HTML go to the URL in your browser and click "view raw". This should return just the document and nothing else. Coppy the URL back into your script and try again.

Third, handle more errors. Once you've got this snippet working handle every error that might occur. No one can guarantee you're going to recive a valid json document (or even some document into first place).